# How do I access images in a certain time period?

Tags: android, gallery

Let's say the time period starts at noon and ends at 2pm. How do I find images in the gallery that fall in between these two times?

Comment: accessing image from where?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] projection = {
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, 
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE
};

// Return only video and image metadata.
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE 
         + " OR "
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
         + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

Uri queryUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
    this,
    queryUri,
    projection,
    selection,
   MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED >= + "HERE START DATE" + "&" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED <= + "HERE END DATE"  ,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC" // Sort order.
  );

Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
```